# rbenv global で設定を行っても、意図したバージョンに切り替わらない

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv

[MacでRails環境構築する手順の全て - Qiita](https://qiita.com/kodai_0122/items/56168eaec28eb7b1b93b) を見て、Ruby 2.5.7, Rails 5.2.3 の構築を目指しています。一度は構築が完了したのですが、何らかの原因で現在は再構築しています。

rbenv（Rubyのバージョン管理ツール）
Ruby
Rails
PostgreSQL（データベース）

そこで、[rbenv global してもバージョンが変らない](https://shikasen-engineer.com/rbenv_global/) を見ながら、ruby 2.5.7 に設定されるよう `rbenv global 2.5.7` 後に `ruby -v` してみても、以下の通り "2.6.3" と表示されてしまいます。

```
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
```

その他に参照して試したこと:
[rbenvを利用して複数バージョンのRubyをインストール - Qiita](https://qiita.com/checkpoint/items/f8e65380d9cb0182218d)
[RubyとRailsのバージョンを変更（ダウングレード）する方法](https://weblion303.net/1548)

どうぞご教授頂けると助かります。

---

ターミナルからshell→コマンド/bin/shを指定しないといけなくなっています。
ですので、/bin/shを指定して作業を行います。

```
$ rbenv versions
  system
  2.5.0
  2.5.1
  2.5.3
* 2.5.7 (set by /Users/XXXXXXXX/.ruby-version)
  2.6.3
  2.6.6

$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

$ rbenv which ruby
/Users/XXXXXXX/.rbenv/versions/2.5.7/bin/ruby

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$ export -p
export HOME="/Users/XXXXXXX”
export LANG="ja_JP.UTF-8"
export LOGNAME=“XXXXXXX”
export OLDPWD
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin"
export PWD="/Users/XXXXXXXX”
export SHELL="/bin/bash"
export SHLVL="1"
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.8NzqzRIZgl/Listeners"
export TERM="xterm-256color"
export TERM_PROGRAM="Apple_Terminal"
export TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION="440"
export TERM_SESSION_ID="C1F542F7-D155-495D-85C4-4D10A38F555E"
export TMPDIR="/var/folders/km/9g8j45755p30v4fnqq5950qr0000gn/T/"
export USER=“XXXXXXX”
export XPC_FLAGS="0x0"
export XPC_SERVICE_NAME="0"
export __CFBundleIdentifier="com.apple.Terminal"
```

- 追加すべきPATHを調べて `sudo vi ~/ .bashrc` で追加してみます。

  参考: [Mac で環境変数PATHの設定・変更・追加・確認・順番入れ替えの方法](https://gabekore.org/mac-path-environmental-variable)
- `!sudo vi ~/.bashrc` 全部削除した。
- `!sudo vi ~/.bash_profile` で `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` を強制追加しました。
- `$ ls -la ~/.bash*`

  ```
  -rw-------  1 XXXXXXX  staff  13338  2 18 10:13 /Users/XXXXXXX/.bash_history
  -rw-r--r--  1 XXXXXXX  staff    174  2 18 10:47 /Users/XXXXXXX/.bash_profile
  -rw-r--r--  1 XXXXXXX  staff  12288  2  9 17:58 /Users/XXXXXXX/.bash_profile.swo
  -rw-r--r--  1 XXXXXXX  staff  12288  2  9 17:25 /Users/XXXXXXX/.bash_profile.swp
  -rw-r--r--  1 XXXXXXX  staff    192  2 18 10:39 /Users/XXXXXXX/.bashrc
  -rw-r--r--  1 root     staff  12288  2 18 10:12 /Users/XXXXXXX/.bashrc.swp

  /Users/XXXXXXXX/.bash_sessions:
  total 760
  省略
  ```

Comment: コメント欄で議論が長引いているようでしたので、この会話をチャットに移動しました。こちらをお使いください： https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119898/discussion-on-question-by-denirou-robata-mac-os-big-surruby-v-rbenv-global-

Comment: 自分自身がオーナーのファイルを編集する場合、`sudo` を使う必要は無いはずです。余計なトラブルの元になるので止めた方が無難です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

まず `.bashrc.swp`というファイルがあって、ユーザがrootになっていますね。
これはviで`.bashrc`を編集中にだけ存在するはずの作業用ファイルで、`sudo vi .bashrc`でできるものですね。`sudo vi 〜`**している最中に**存在するのはなにも問題ないですが、そうでないときに存在するのはおかしいです。
viを強制終了してしまって残ったりしたとかであれば、`sudo rm .bashrc.swp`で消しましょう。

---

`export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv:$PATH"`が4行あるのが`.bashrc`でしょうか。
全部要らないので削除してください。

---

`#Add Visual Studio Code`で始まる3行の部分、2行目3行目が不完全です。間違った手段でなにかをしてしまったと思います。2行目でPATHの設定をおかしくして、3行目がエラーになっているはずです。
消しましょう。（"ターミナルからshell→コマンド/bin/shを指定しないといけなくなって"いるのはこの2行のせいでは?）

`eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"`の行、**zshの設定をbashに追加してはいけません**。
また`eval "$(rbenv init -)"`があればそれで十分ですので↑の行は消しましょう。

Visual Studio Codeの設定はあとでどうにかするとして、今は`eval "$(rbenv init -)"`の行だけあればいいでしょう。

Comment: 大変ご迷惑をお掛けします。削除します。

Comment: 括弧書きの場所がおかしかったです。すみません。"要らない"のは export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv:$PATH" でした。

Comment: 解決しませんか?

Comment: すいません。私用でまだやっていませんでした。これからやってみます。

Answer (score 0):

[Rubyのバージョンが切り替わらない時の対処法！](https://qiita.com/opiyo_taku/items/3312a75d5916f6cd32b1)

を見て、以下の手順で変更をPCに反映させると無事成功！お騒がせしました。

```sh
$ cd
$ vi ~/.bash_profile 

export PATH="~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:$PATH" 
eval "$(rbenv init -)" 

$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: export PATH="~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:$PATH" は不要（というか eval "$(rbenv init -)" でやってくれる）かと思います。